# export mpicc in a bash script (for OpenFoam)

Tags: bash, redhat-enterprise-linux, export

I am not able to execute this line via script properly:

```
export PATH=/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin:$PATH;
```

or writing it to a file and sourcing the file:

```
echo "export PATH=/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin:$$PATH" >> shrc;
source shrc;
```

when I lunch the openFoam Installation afterwards it tells me "command not found mpicc" only when I directly type it myself into the commandline everything works just fine.

(the script is executed using a function therefor I source the script before executing the function - mpicc is not in conflict with other variables)

(I also tried setting mpicc as alias with the complete path "/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpicc" and also tried to export not only the bin directory but the direct path to mpicc to $PATH - nothing worked)

How can I run this command by script so that ./Allwmake of OpenFOAM will be able to find it?

(Using BASH, RHEL 7.6 (Maipo))

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You say you are not able to execute the line `export PATH=/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin:$PATH;`.  What does that mean?  Does it give an error message, or does it just leave you unable to run `mpicc`?  You say tried defining `mpicc` as alias with the complete path `/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpicc` and that didn’t work. The obvious questions are: what happens when you just type `/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpicc` into the shell?  What does ``ls -ld /usr/lib64/openmpi/bin/mpicc`` say?

Comment: Yes I tried both but the question was indeed unclear because I was able to run mpicc from commandline w/o the full path but still the script wasn't able to run mpicc from commandline. This could be fixed following the instruction from your answer. (Still I have no clue why it is needed to echo the export to a bashrc file to source this file afterwards instead of just directly extending the path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your second command block is flawed: that’s not the way to echo a `$`. 
You must do either

```
echo "export PATH=/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin:\$PATH"
```

(using `\$`), or

```
echo 'export PATH=/usr/lib64/openmpi/bin:$PATH'
```

(using single quotes, and an unadorned `$`).

Comment: For some reason I thought $ is passed in bash by doubeling it (escaping) - will test and report, thanks so far